# Detect homepage with jQuery conflicting with .htaccess

Tags: jquery, .htaccess

I have been checking if the page is index.php using the following jquery...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.href == "www.mydomain.com/index.php"){
     alert('This is the homepage');
        }   
    });
</script>
```

All has been working fine but I have now introduced a .htaccess file to get rid of the .php extension from files like so...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I have now lost the php extension from the URLs which is what I wanted but now my page detection script no longer works.  I have modified the jQuery snippet to remove the .php...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.href == "www.mydomain.com"){
     alert('This is the homepage');
        }   
    });
</script>
```

Am I detecting the homepage in the correct way or is there a more efficient way to do it that works with my .htaccess file?

Comment: If you got rid of the .php, then get rid of the php from the js as well. `window.location.href == "www.mydomain.com"`

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that.  I have removed the .php from the script but it no longer works

Comment: Then do `if (window.location.pathname === "/")`

Comment: I think `window.location.pathname === "/"` is better check than `location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       if ( window.location.href == "http://www.domain.com/index.php" ||
            window.location.href == "http://www.domain.com/"
         ) {
          alert('This is the homepage');
       }   
    });
</script>
```

As `window.location.href` starts with `http://`

PS: As @dave comments you are better off to check for this condition:

```
window.location.pathname === "/"
```

Comment: But the URL no longer contains /index.php

Comment: As i've already stated in the op, I have removed the /index.php and it no longer works

Comment: Try my updated answer and also tell me what is the exact URL you see in browser

Comment: I see www.mydomain.com - the updated answer doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you do: `console.log(window.location.pathname);` and see what it prints

Comment: console.log(window.location.pathname); returns /

Comment: In that case `if ( window.location.pathname == "/" )` condition should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to match the following:

```
/

index

index.php
```

To see, print out the contents of

```
console.log(window.location.href)
```

Then you should be able to see the string it needs to match.

Though I'm wondering if it might be better to just move the script to live inside the index page content.  That way it's event driven, and not testing the url.

Answer (score 0):

First I would do a simple .htaccess file and add these to the end of it. That way if the file doesn't exist and the user doesn't ask for anything but the home page, then index.php?ISHOME=1 is loaded.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?ISHOME=1 [NC,L]
```

Next, in the index.php file, add the following code somewhere after the initial HTML processing routines:

```
if (intval($_POST['ISHOME']) == 1){
    echo "<script>\n";
    echo "alert('This is the homepage')\n";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

No Jquery required. Just a simple one-liner alert.